# Using Both Express.js and Http module in NodeJS application

Tags: node.js, express, http, soap

Currently, I am developing a simple project, which uses strong-soap module and expressjs. To create a soap server, I have to use http module of NodeJs, using express for soap module causes errors (wsdl file content can't be seen in browser). And i declare my routes and its functions by help of ExpressJS. My simple codebase is similar to the given below.

**index.js**

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http');

var MyServiceObject = { /* ...some methods which exist in wsdl file */ };

var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('myWsdlFile.wsdl');

let server = http.createServer(function(request,response) {
    response.end("404: Not Found: " + request.url);
});

server.listen(8000);
soap.listen(server, '/wsdl', MyServiceObject, xml);

/*###########################  SOME ROUTES ############################################*/

app.listen(8002, (req, res) => {
  console.log('App is listening on port 8002');
});
```

I am concerning about security, so i have a long question:
I'm not able to apply some authorization processes on HTTP Object in my code. How i can apply authorization on http? Is leaving http object as seen in code block, causes some security problems? Must i apply some authorization processes on http object? And i am using strong-soap server in this project. Must i apply some authorization processes on strong-soap object also. I can apply authorization processes on Express.js. Is applying authorization processes on express object (app) is sufficient for security?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP Authorization in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73278776/http-authorization-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the **soap** package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap), you will get more flexibility to work with. Also, you can install the soap client (https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui/) to test services before implementing them with Node.js. It will help you to understand the request and response of each service.